# What is the opposite of a derangement?

Tags: functions, terminology, derangements

A [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) is a bijection $f : A \rightarrow A$ such that $f(x) \ne x$ for all $x \in A$.

Is there a name for a bijection $f : A \rightarrow A$ that is *not* a derangement? That is, is there a name for a bijection $f : A \rightarrow A$ where $f(x) = x$ for at least on $x \in A$?

Thanks!

Comment: Bijection with at least on fixed point?

Comment: This is a hard question, since names depend on conventions, I looked up on some references, there was no such a name. Why do you ask that?

Comment: @ConradoCosta I'm teaching a discrete math course and a question came up where it was useful to talk about functions with this property. I ended up calling them "non-derangements," but it sounded really silly.

Comment: @ConradoCosta Oh, I wasn't planning on just having students memorize the names for things. I was hoping to have students spend a decent amount of time proving things about these functions and wanted to make sure that if there was an appropriate name for these functions that I would use it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers Explains the "Rencontres numbers" from French "rencontre" = "casual meeting". I came upon it while searching for "partial derangement".